# Fullcalendar 2 week view on 1 row

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to configure [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to display 2 weeks, but on one row.

I have tried setting up a custom view with the following, which works, but it displays 1 week per row

```
 views: {
     twoWeek: {
         type: 'basic',
         duration: { weeks: 2 },
         buttonText: '2 weeks'
     }
 }
```

Changing the type to agenda is slightly better in that the 2 weeks are displayed on one row, but as all my events are all day events I don't need to display the time grid, just the all day section. Another issue with the agenda view is that the all day section doesn't have a scrollbar and I would like to limit the height of the calendar, so would need a scrollbar.

Basically I would like to 2 week view to look similar to this

[2 week view single row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kluLM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

it may be a little late, but I am now wokring with this fullcalendar library, to achieve what you want, just need to change the type of calendar you are using.

```
views: {
     twoWeek: {
         type: 'agenda',
         duration: { weeks: 2 },
         buttonText: '2 weeks'
     }
 }
```